# Refactoring session variables

Tags: asp.net, session, refactoring, session-variables

I'm visiting an app that's been in use for the past 2+ years and it is in desperate need of refactoring.  It is of my own work, but you know what it's like when you visit old code again.

Anyway I've been using the [excellent advice at sourcemaking](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring) to refactor and the code is already looking much better.

The problem now is there are loads of Session["variable"] sprinkled throughout the code, so what's the most accepted way to refactor these out?  I found [this article at code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/wrapthosesessionvariables.aspx?msg=2229362) but apparently it can be quite dangerous.

Comment: The warning that the code is dangerous says that it is if you are testing "multiple users" by opening several tabs in IE. This isn't what a real multiple user scenario would work like, each different visitor has their own Session.

Comment: So do you agree that the article is fine for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to refactor random session usage like this is to create a static `SessionWrapper` with static properties that encapsulate the ASP.NET session store:

```
static class SessionWrapper
{
    public static string Variable
    {
        get { return Session["variable"]; }
        set { Session["variable"] = value; }
    }
}
```

This will also allow you to put some logic around the getting and setting of these values and keep them in a centralized place.

I would also strongly recommend that you have some integration tests in place before you start this process so that you can be sure you haven't missed anything.

Comment: One more advantage of this method is no type checking is needed everywhere.